# Oracle dbms_scheduler.run_job invalid username/password

Tags: windows, oracle, security, scheduler

I'm trying to set up a scheduled external job using Oracle to call a batch file. I've found a lot of material on the net that talks about this, however I'm missing something.

I'm running my PL/SQL in SQL Developer (but I've tried in in SQLPlus as well). The error I'm getting in the output window is the following.

```
Error starting at line 7 in command:
exec dbms_scheduler.run_job('my_job')
Error report:
ORA-27369: job of type EXECUTABLE failed with exit code: The storage control blocks were destroyed.
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_ISCHED", line 185
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER", line 486
ORA-06512: at line 1
27369. 00000 -  "job of type EXECUTABLE failed with exit code: %s"
*Cause:    A problem was encountered while running a job of type EXECUTABLE.
           The cause of the actual problem is identified by the exit code.
*Action:   Correct the cause of the exit code and reschedule the job.
```

The error I'm getting in dba_scheduler_job_run_details is the following.

```
"EXTERNAL_LOG_ID="job_167045_46155",
ORA-27369: job of type EXECUTABLE failed with exit code: The storage control blocks were destroyed.
STANDARD_ERROR="Launching external job failed: Invalid username or password""
```

I figure that it's some kind of permission problem either with where my batch file is located or something. I'm trying to run the job as a maintenance account. If I use the Windows cmd line "runas" command and run my batch file directly, everything is fine. If I run through Oracle, it doesn't. I've tried different accounts such as an admin account, however it made no difference.

The code I used to create my credential/job follows.

```
exec dbms_scheduler.create_credential( credential_name => 'oracle_cred', username => 'user', password => 'password', windows_domain => 'domain' );

DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job ('my_job',
                          job_action => 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CMD.EXE',
                          number_of_arguments => 2,
                          start_date=> sysdate+1,
                          auto_drop=>FALSE,
                          job_type => 'executable',
                          enabled => FALSE
);   

DBMS_SCHEDULER.set_job_argument_value ('my_job', 1, '/C');
DBMS_SCHEDULER.set_job_argument_value ('my_job', 2, 'C:\maintenance\audit.bat');
dbms_scheduler.set_attribute('my_job', 'credential_name', 'oracle_cred');
DBMS_SCHEDULER.enable('my_job');
```

Any suggestions are appreciated,

mj

Comment: The error seems to indicate that Oracle can't connect to the windows domain with this user/password. Can you check the system or secure logs for login errors? Does this work without a domain with a local user account?

Comment: You're right. The issue was that my Windows user had some permissions to execute only batch jobs and not log in. Once I changed that it worked fine.